# java: how to duplicate value with different parameter type

Tags: java, spring, model, dto

I have problems with my spring code, and I am trying hard to find a solution.

I would like to parse my values from dto to model and vice versa with different parameter types.

Here are the SC:
UserModel:

```
public Class UserModel {
private int userId;
private Date dob;
//setter getter
}
```

UserDto:

```
public Class UserDto {
private String userId;
private String dob;
//setter getter
}
```

I have tried a lot of methods such as using ObjectMapper and PropertyUtilsBean, and it keeps show error.

Anyone of you has the best solution? Please Help

Comment: FIrst of all, `date` should be `Date`. Also, you need to tell us, what error you are getting.

Comment: ok thanks... I will edit the question...

if  use PropertyUtilsBean :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination bean specified... 

if use ObjectMapper:  org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.mycore.thebe.entity.User. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.*;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateConverter;

import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateConverter converter = new DateConverter();
        converter.setPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

        ConvertUtilsBean convertUtilsBean = new ConvertUtilsBean();
        convertUtilsBean.register(converter, Date.class);

        BeanUtilsBean beanUtilsBean = new BeanUtilsBean(convertUtilsBean, new PropertyUtilsBean());

        UserDto dto = new UserDto("42", "2018-11-14");
        System.out.println("dto.getUserId() = " + dto.getUserId());
        System.out.println("dto.getDob() = " + dto.getDob());

        UserModel model = new UserModel();
        beanUtilsBean.copyProperties(model, dto);

        System.out.println("model.getUserId() = " + model.getUserId());
        System.out.println("model.getDob() = " + model.getDob());
    }

}
```

You can find full example source code [here](https://github.com/ygor-sk/stackoverflow/tree/master/q53295382-propertyutilsbean).

Comment: I have tried it, but it come with error.....   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log

Comment: I can execute my example from IntelliJ and also from Maven using `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=sk.ygor.stackoverflow.q53295382.Main`. I  believe, that your exception has nothing to do with `PropertyUtilsBean`. Please send the whole stacktrace.